# Serve custom static files with socket.io nodejs

Tags: node.js, static, socket.io, share

I try to share my code betwen server and client I use following code (app.js):

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000), 
  Static = require('socket.io').Static; 

io.configure(function () {
  var _static = new Static(io); 

  // some methods to add my custom files 

  _static.add('\public\test.js');
  io.set('static', _static);
});
```

My file structure looks like this:

1. root

   - app.js
   - public

     - test.js

When I type "http://localhost:8000/public.test.js" Browser download default file "Welcome to socket.io"

Answer (score 7):

This question is rather old, but here's the current way to do it (for v0.9):

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);
io.static.add('/path/for/request.js', {file: 'path/to/file.js'});
```

Note that the path to the resource is relative to the socket.io path, so the request URI would be something like:

```
http://localhost:8000/socket.io/path/for/request.js
```

If you see an error like `Protocol version not supported`, then that means your request URI probably has an extension that the manager can't support. Here's how to add that support:

```
io.static.add('/path/for/request.foo', {
  mime: {
    type: 'application/javascript',
    encoding: 'utf8',
    gzip: true
  },
  file: 'path/to/file.js'
});
```

The documentation points at [their own Static library](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/0.9.14/lib/static.js#L108) for a working implementation.

Comment: damn, Just read the first 3 lines & spent 60 minutes on, "why the path is not working!!!" ewww..

Comment: how do you serve all the files in a folder?

Comment: i am not able to find documentation for io.static.add. could you point me one?

Comment: The repo has been updated for the "upcoming" 1.0 release, and the documentation is [in the readme](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/tree/64f6b244b6bd79880ba2e0ba00778a2309b39d0b#serverstaticvbooleanserver). For v0.9, to which this answer refers, the wiki points at [their own implementation](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/0.9.14/lib/static.js#L108)

Comment: the `'path/to/file.js'` seems to be relative to some socket.io directory I could not find. If you use `__dirname + '/path/to/file.js'` instead this becomes relative to your current js-file (most likely your app.js)